# iOS prototype debugging,Swift Compiler Error

Tags: ios, swift, prototype

When I do the prototype debugging,the Xcode6.2 said

```
could not build Objective-C module 'UIKit'

/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:9: 'QuartzCore/CATransform3D.h' file not found
```

But Everything is Ok when I run the code on iOS Simulator
Error Only happened when prototype debugging.

Is there anything wrong with my Build Setting?

Comment: What is "prototype debugging"?

Comment: Run the app on the iphone

Comment: Delete Xcode and reinstall.